# Why can I not cast an object with a value of 24 to a double?

Tags: c#

Here is the code that I have:

```
var a = Application.Current.Resources[FontSize];
```

The debugger shows 24 when I hover over `a`

```
var fs = (double)Application.Current.Resources[FontSize];
```

The line above gives me an error saying it cannot be cast to a double.

Can anyone help and give me advice on how to cast an object that shows as being `24` to a double?

Comment: Try this `Convert.ToDouble(Application.Current.Resources[FontSize])` If this does not work, what is the value of `Console.WriteLine(Application.Current.Resources[FontSize]);`?

Comment: What is the *type* of `a` at compile time?  Does the debugger *really* show the value as `24` as you claim, or does it perhaps show the value as `"24"`?  There's a significant difference.

Comment: Class System.Object

Comment: @iamsophia: an `Object` can't be cast to a primative value.  You may need to append `.ToString()` to the object and use `double.TryParse()` to parse it.

Comment: I tried double.Parse(Application.Current.Resources[FontSize]); and it gives a compile error saying cannot convert from double to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can't cast `string` to `double`, you should use `double.Parse(a)` or `double.TryParse(a, out var number)` or If the return type is object `double.Parse(a.ToString())` or `double.TryParse(a.ToString(), out var number)`

Comment: I tried double.Parse(Application.Current.Resources[FontSize]); and it gives a compile error saying cannot convert from double to string.

Comment: @iamsophia put `ToString()` at the end.

Comment: Works now.  thanks and I will accept soon

Comment: @iamsophia Converting the value to string is very redundant if it is something that is actually already convertible to a double – check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`Application.Current.Resources` is a dictionary with `object` keys and `object` values. The expression `(double)o`, when `o` is an object, means unboxing a value with type `System.Double` that is stored inside the object. The debugger tells you that the value inside the object is 24, but it didn't tell you its type – the cast will only succeed if the type is *exactly* `System.Double`, and not (for example) `System.Int32`.

Check the result of `a.GetType()`. If you get `System.Int32` for example, you should first cast it to `int` and then `double` (if you want to). Usually values coming from the same source with the same semantics will have the same type, so if you can guarantee this, all is fine.

If you can't say for sure that the value inside `a` will always have the same type, then you need a conversion, not a cast:

```
var fs = Convert.ToDouble(Application.Current.Resources[FontSize], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will attempt to convert the value inside to `double` and will succeed if it is convertible to it. Note that `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will ensure the conversion is consistent across any language setting (which matters especially for floating-point values stored as strings).